# Pass api response from one component to another component in Angular

Tags: angular, api, rest, angular-services, angular-components

I have a component named server and another component named process. I am taking response from server.service.ts to server.component.ts and I want that response in process.component.ts. Any ideas on how this can be achieved.

p.s. the API response is n array of strings.

Comment: You can use `Subject`, `BehaviorSubject` or `Input`. The choice is yours.

Comment: okay trying them.. thanks for your suggestions @JacopoSciampi

Comment: I suggest you to not use `input` tho, since they trigger the `ChangeDetection` very often and this could results in an unwanted overall slowness of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to pass informations from one component to another component:

- If they are parent child you can pass it using @Input and @Output (it depends on the direction you need to use)
- If they are in different pages you can pass it in various ways using the routing (route parameter, query string, url fragment, state object)
- You can save the information in a service
- You can use a Subject to which the first component will next the object and the second component is subscribed to get the updates

Comment: Subject would fit best in my case. But when I implemented it, it is not getting subscribed in my next component.

Comment: Also the components are different pages of the application

Comment: You need to use a service holding the Subject. If it is possible that the first component send the daa before the second component made the subscription simply use a BehaviourSubject instead